# MySQL find common path

Tags: mysql

I want to find common parent folder in my table images with field path.
For example, in my table i have for this table 6 rows.

1      c:\images\site1\root\img\logo.png

2      c:\images\site1\root\resource\test1.png

3      c:\images\site1\root\resource\test2.png

4      c:\images\site1\root\resource\test3.png

5      c:\images\site1\root\images\background.png

And I want to have "root" folders:
c:\images\site1\root\img\
c:\images\site1\root\resource\
c:\images\site1\root\images\
What is the SQL request to get this, please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a bit tricky.  If you know that the path does not share the name of the file, you could replace the last part with an empty string:

```
select distinct replace(path, substring_index(path, '\\', -1), '')
```

However, this may not always be true.

What you want is everything before the last occurrence of `\\`.  Here is a method using `substring_index()`:

```
select distinct substring_index(path, '\\',
                                length(path) - length(replace(path, '\\', '')
                               )
```

The difference in lengths is simply counting the number of separator characters in the string.  If the path has one separator (i.e. 'a\b'), then the argument to `substring_index()` is 1, which is what you want.

Comment: i Gordon it's working!thank you very much you save my day...and my life!